# How can I find the first time an element occurs for the second time?

Tags: python

I would like to find the first time an element occurs for the second time in a list.  For example, if my list was

```
['1','2','1B','2B','2B','2','1B','1']
```

the result should be `'2B'` (or it could return the index 4), since the element '2B' is the first element to occur twice (going left to right).

I know I can do this with a basic for loop counting occurrences as I go along; I just wondered what's the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: Your loop has a complexity `O(n)` if you store the occurrence count in a dictionary, you cannot find anything faster since you need at least to read the whole list

Comment: Okay, that's basically the answer I was looking for.

Comment: `next(n for i, n in enumerate(l) if n in l[:i])` – Pretty inefficient, but a one-liner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could loop over the elements in the list, keep track of which have appeared by adding them to a `set`, and `break` as soon as an element is already in the set:

```
l = ['1','2','1B','2B','2B','2','1B','1']

s = set()
for i in l:
    if i in s:
        result = i
        break
    else:
        s.add(i)
```

---

```
print(result)
# '2B'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't do better than worst case `O(N)`. If you want be concise and don't mind some side-effect kung-fu, you can use `next` with a conditional generator:

```
lst = ['1','2','1B','2B','2B','2','1B','1']
s = set()
next(x for x in lst if x in s or s.add(x))
# '2B'
```

Comment: @yatu in my view, this adds nothing over your answer and detracts from readability

Comment: @Chris_Rands Absolutely, this is purely academical. I'd kill any team member who'd put that in production code :) hence the disclaimer

Comment: Yes agreed this is definitely less readable, nonetheless that does not mean you cannot like or appreciate more *hacky* answers @Chris_Rands :)

Comment: I appreciate the aesthetic of such solutions, but i think they belong on Code Golf rather than SO

Comment: @Chris_Rands Agreed. However, questions à la "I know how I can do it with a loop and a counter, but is there a better/faster/shorter way..." are kind of asking for it.

Comment: Yah i agree with you there

Comment: @ilmiacs It will break as soon as the first duplicate is found.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
appearance = set()
data = ['1','2','1B','2B','2B','2','1B','1']


for i, d in enumerate(data):
    if d in appearance:
        print(i)
        break
    else:
        appearance.add(d)
```

**Output**

```
4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = ['1','2','1B','2B','2B','2','1B','1'] 
d = {}
for i in x:
    if not i in d: 
        d[i] = 0
    else:
        print(i)
        break
```

output

```
2B
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution but not as efficient as yatu's answer.

```
l = ['1','2','1B','2B','2B','2','1B','1'] 

next(x for i, x in enumerate(l, 1) if len(l[:i]) > len(set(l[:i])))

# '2B'
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the great answers posted, it's worth mentioning [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> ls = ['1','2','1B','2B','2B','2','1B','1']
>>> seen = set()
>>> len(list(takewhile(lambda x: x not in seen and not seen.add(x), ls)))
4
```

or

```
>>> list(takewhile(lambda x: x not in seen and not seen.add(x), ls)).pop()
'2B'
```

The above raises `IndexError` if the list is empty and both methods return the whole list if all items are unique, requiring a bit of interpretation.

This also generates a temporary list (unlike the explicit loop approach) and is not especially readable, but at least only performs a partial traversal when a dupe does exist and makes it easy to get the index or the group of elements to the left of the duplicate.